# Spring Boot JPA/Hibernate PostgreSQL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

so I'm trying to  implement da db I found online for a school project.I have experience with ASP.NET Core and Enitty Framework Core but I had never worked before with spring.
This is how the db looks like:
[image]

So my question is the following:
    How my movieCast entity would look like if i want to save in it an List of Actors not just an actor?

Answer (score 0):

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "actorId", insertable=false, updatable=false)
Actor actor;

@Column(name = "actorId", nullable=false)
Long actorId;
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Many-To-Many Relationship

You have differents ways to reach your goal

More informations check the [link](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many)